# Foundation 5 nested on small and not nested on large

Tags: jquery, html, grid, nested, zurb-foundation-5

I'm new to this, and i've stumbled into a more complex grid situation

**HTML**

```
<section id="management">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
   <h3>TITLE 1</h3>
   <p>Some text for title 1</p>
   <a id="tab1" class="btn tab" role="button" title="Tarefas Básicas">Show Content 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
   <h3>TITLE 2</h3>
   <p>Some text for title 2</p>
   <a id="tab2" class="btn tab" role="button" title="Tarefas Básicas">Show Content 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
   <h3>TITLE 3</h3>
   <p>Some text for title 3</p>
   <a id="tab3" class="btn tab" role="button" title="Tarefas Básicas">Show Content 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 large-3 columns">
   <h3>TITLE 4</h3>
   <p>Some text for title 4</p>
   <a id="tab4" class="btn tab" role="button" title="Tarefas Básicas">Show Content 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tasks">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="tab1show" class="tab-content">
    <h3>HIDE CONTENT 1</h3>
    <p>Some Text for content 1 needed to be a bit longer</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2show" class="tab-content">
    <h3>HIDE CONTENT 2</h3>
    <p>Some Text for content 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab3show" class="tab-content">
    <h3>HIDE CONTENT 3</h3>
    <p>Some Text for content 3</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab4show" class="tab-content">
    <h3>HIDE CONTENT 4</h3>
    <p>Some Text for content 4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $contents = $('.tab-content');
 $contents.slice().hide();
 $('.tab').click(function() {
 var $target = $('#' + this.id + 'show').toggle();
 $contents.not($target).hide();
});
```

http://codepen.io/lookshinji/pen/YXgNMP

So trying to explain what i want to achieve: 
I Have a show/hide content trough jQuery and that is working as expected, but it shows content after all those visible content, which on large screens is perfect. But when i go on a small screen i get each visible content stacked one after another, if i click show, the content appears after everything, and the user can't see it, so i would like to show it straight after each visible content on mobile.

If i leave like it is i have a problem on mobile, and if I move eache hidden content inside each visible i have a problem with the grid on large screens cause my content is large for only 3 columns, would anyone have any idea how to display this in a better way?

Comment: You could duplicate the show/hide div's and then make it so that you clicking on the link shows both of them. Once you have that working, use media queries to make it so one of the divs is only visible on small screens and the other is only visible on large screens.